# How to run prototxt file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, caffe

I have a problem in applying Super-Resolution Convolutional Neural Networks (SRCNN).
In SRCNN code, the 'Readme.txt' file tells

1. Place the "SRCNN" folder into "($Caffe_Dir)/examples/"
2. Open MATLAB and direct to ($Caffe_Dir)/example/SRCNN, run 
   "generate_train.m" and "generate_test.m" to generate training and test data.
3. To train our SRCNN, run
   ./build/tools/caffe train --solver examples/SRCNN/SRCNN_solver.prototxt
4. After training, you can extract parameters from the caffe model and save them in the format that can be used in our test package (SRCNN_v1). To do this, you need to install mat-caffe first, then open MATLAB and direct to ($Caffe_Dir) and run "saveFilters.m". The "($Caffe_Dir)/examples/SRCNN/x3.mat" will be there for you.

In number 3, I don't know how to run prototxt file in Matlab.
So there is anyone to help me running prototxt file in Maytlab?
I want some example code to run prototxt file in Matlab.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using R2017a. I tried importCaffeNetwork but it required 'prototxt' and 'caffemodel'. I have only prototxt file. The data file is HDF5 and I don't know how to change HDF5 file to caffemodel.

Comment: isn't it written how to run that?  `./build/tools/caffe train --solver examples/SRCNN/SRCNN_solver.prototxt`

Comment: Does that command run in MATLAB? I don't know how to use that command.

Comment: run that command in the terminal